# PyCharm pytest GUI runs tests, terminal doesn't

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

I'm trying to run pytest from within a script, so I want it to run all test files by simply invoking `pytest` with no arguments. However, pytest doesn't collect the testfiles.

Hirarchy is as follows

```
project
  -somedirectory
    --somecode.py
  -tests
    --test.py
```

`test.py` look as follows

```
def test_one():
  assert True
```

Running pytest via the PyCharm GUI works as expected, `test.py` is collected, run and passed.

Running `pytest tests/test.py` works as expected, `test.py` is collected, run and passed.

Running `pytest` without arguments does not work as expected, it doesn't collect `test.py`.

Running `pwd` returns `/path/to/project`.

The behaviour is the same for Windows command prompt and the PyCharm terminal.

Comment: What about `pytest tests`?

Comment: By default pytest looks for files with the pattern "test_*.py" of "*_test.py", your file "test.py" doesn't match these patterns so is likely being ignored. Try renaming it to something else? "test_foo.py" for example

Answer (score 0):

> By default pytest looks for files with the pattern "test_*.py", your file "test.py" doesn't match this pattern so is likely being ignored. Try renaming it to something else? "test_foo.py" for example

This works. I did not realise the naming convention related to files as well as functions.